# get captcha from a website

Tags: android, jsoup, captcha

how can i get captcha from [this](http://self.tcsh.ac.ir/) website?
I tried to get it with code below but it doesn't work!

```
Document document =Jsoup.connect("http://self.tcsh.ac.ir/").ignoreContentType(true).get();
Element captchaElement = document.select("#Plan1 img").first();
String captchaImgSrc = captchaElement.attr("src");
InputStream inputStream = new URL("http://self.tcsh.ac.ir" + captchaImgSrc).openStream();
captcha = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
ImageView captchaImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.captcha_img);
captchaImage.setImageBitmap(captcha);
```

what should I do to get Captcha from the website?
And also I want to user write words in captcha and after that I send it to server and access to next page? what should i do for that?
Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do is called hotlinking the captcha, and most sites prevent you from doing this.

Comment: nobody outside Iran can access this site.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I have replace that with reachable one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in your element's ID. it is not `Plan1`, but `Panel1`:

```
<div id="Panel1">
```

So your selector should look like this:

```
Element captchaElement = document.select("#Panel1 img").first();
```